# Store checkbox group in @Html.HiddenFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In one view, I have a group of checkboxes that map to a `List<int>`.

View:

```
<input name="foo.IntegerList" type="checkbox" value="1"> 
<input name="foo.IntegerList" type="checkbox" value="2"> 
<input name="foo.IntegerList" type="checkbox" value="3"> 
<input name="foo.IntegerList" type="checkbox" value="4"> 
<input name="foo.IntegerList" type="checkbox" value="5">
```

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
<public ActionResult DoStuff(Foo foo)
    //do stuff
```

Model:

```
public class Foo
{
    IEnumerable<int> IntegerList
}
```

Submitting this form posts to the DoStuff action gives it a populated `List<int>`.

Now, I have to use `IntegerList` in another view, and as a hidden field. In another view, I use this code:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.IntegerList)
```

But this gets translated to the following HTML:

```
<input name="IntegerList" type="hidden" value="">
```

Note that the value isn't set. How do I make `Html.HiddenFor` generate the correct hidden field?

Comment: What do you expect `value` to be? if you want generate hidden fileds for all selected checkboxes, then use `for` loop and generate hidden input for each of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate over them an put the name with an index:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.IntegerList.Count; i++)
    <input name="IntegerList[@i]" type="hidden" value="@Model.IntegerList[i]">
}
```

With `HiddenFor` it's done like this

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.IntegerList.Count; i++)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.IntegerList[i])
}
```

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but I guess beggars can't be choosers. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't had time to compile and maybe has some compile errors, but this is the way to do it. Any by compile errors, `IEnumerable` I don't remember to contain the `Count` property, maybe you need to covert it to a list or array.

Answer (score 0):

in your model

```
public class Foo
{
 public string[] IntegerList{ get; set; }
}
```

in your method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(Foo foo)
{
 if (foo.IntegerList!= null)
 string val = String.Join(",", foo.IntegerList);
}
```

your hiddenfield like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(p => p.IntegerList , new { @id = "IntegerList"})
<input name="IntegerList" id="IntegerList" type="hidden" value="">
```

in jquery

```
var Values = [];
 $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
 if (this.checked) {
    Values.push($(this).val());
 }
 else{
    Values.pop(this);
 }
});

$('#IntegerList').val(Values).appendTo('form');
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just wanted to share what worked for me. This is a modification to @adricadar's solution:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.MySelections)
{
    <input name="MySelections" type="hidden" value="@item" />
}
```